# Where can I find ISAPI-DLL entry in ApplicationHost.config file

Tags: iis, isapi

I need to verify `ApplicationHost.config` file for the IIS configuration for my website, programmatically.
Here I am reading the `ApplicationHost.config` file and making sure that all the configuration exists as per website needs.
I am facing problem while verifying `'Edit Feature Permissions'` for ISAPI-DLL under `'Handler Mapping'`.
When I change Feature Permission for ISAPI-DLL to `execute` I am not getting the updated value in the `ApplicationHost.config` file. Could someone please help me on this ?

[image]
Attached Screenshot [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I was looking in the wrong file. IIS made changes in the `web.config` file of the Application folder.
So to validate whether `execute` permission is given to ISAPI-DLL handler I read the attribute `accessPolicy` of Node `handlers` 
Below are the sample xml.

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <remove name="ISAPI-dll" />
            <add name="ISAPI-dll" path="*.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\software\_WebNeo_SQL_Sample_Site_1\rest\ttmRESTSrv.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" preCondition="bitness32" />
        </handlers>
```